# python aiohttp server and client with asyncio

Tags: python, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I am running an aiohttp server. It's taking request one by one, and works fine.

```
from aiohttp import web

async def hello(request):
    return web.Response(text='done')

app = web.Application()
app.add_routes([web.get('/', hello)])

web.run_app(app)
```

Now I need to make two slow outgoing requests one by one. I am thinking to put in the aiohttp client code into the hello function. So when the server is waiting for the outbound requests coming back, it can serve the next inbound request.

```
async def hello(request):


        async def fetch(session, url):
            with async_timeout.timeout(10):
                async with session.get(url) as response:
                    return await response.text()

        async def main(loop):
            async with aiohttp.ClientSession(loop=loop) as session:
                html1 = await fetch(session, URL1)
                html2 = await fetch(session, URL2)

        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        loop.run_until_complete(main(loop))

    return web.Response(text='done')
```

The above html1 and html2 will go out simultaneously. How can I make the second fetch when the first fetch is finished? Or some other design can help?

Comment: `html1` will be completely loaded before `html2` in your example. Why do you think they are being executed in parallel?

Comment: I thought it goes to fetch the URL1. Without html1 coming back, it's fetching the URL2 as they are async?

Comment: They are asynchronous but that doesn't mean they run at the same time. For them to run in parallel you'd have to do `html1, html2 = await asyncio.gather(fetch(URL1), fetch(URL2))`. Think of `await` as a part of the code that tells the interpreter that it can go work on other stuff while the current task is pending. When the HTML has been fetched, the interpreter comes back and continues running your code where it left off.

Comment: It's interesting to learn that "they are asynchronous but that doesn't mean they run at the same time". So back to the first code block, if the fetch an URL is in the hello function, and 10 requests coming in. The 10 requests are served one by one, even the CPU is idle while fetching. Is that correct?

Comment: Not quite. `aiohttp` will accept every request you send to it and begin responding to each one immediately (otherwise, what would be the benefit of using an asynchronous HTTP server?). All your code is still running in a single thread, so you won't actually be executing two pieces of code at exactly the same time, just switching contexts every time you have to wait for something slow to happen (i.e. the `await`s). But when 99% of your time is spent waiting for data to come in over the network, this approach works just fine (and is used by webservers like nginx).

Comment: `await x; await y` means that first `x` will be executed, then `y`. `await foo` means that the current coroutine will be suspended until `foo` is ready. Neither of those conflicts with **other** coroutines running at the same time. In other words, it is not correct that the 10 requests are served one by one, because there is no `await` that would force them into sequential order.